# Does anyone have experience kickstarting "Notes" into WorkFront/AtTask?

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Does anyone have experience kickstarting information into the "Updates" field within projects and tasks? I've been using the "Notes" template and have been getting errors regarding the ObjID. I'm just not sure what information goes into each required field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ObjID just needs to be unique within your spreadsheet and the isNew set to True. Just learning this stuff myself for Project and hours type imports.

Comment: Thank you for your response! We're Kickstarting projects, tasks, and issues and want to kickstart notes for data elements that aren't going on the custom form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to couple it with noteObjCode=TASK or PROJ or OPTASK (for Issues).  The ObjID is the alphanumeric value that you see when looking at the task, project, or issue.  If you are creating new ones then you'd have to capture the post response of the object you create, use the new ID as the ObjID, and add the subsequent notes to it that way.

Just realized I gave you an API solution to your question. You would need to know the IDs of the objects you want to attach to. If you have your tasks and projects in you could create a report with their ids and map in excel with VLOOKUP to populate. Hope this was helpful

Comment: Just realized I gave you an API solution to your question.  You would need to know the IDs of the objects you want to attach to.  If you have your tasks and projects in you could create a report with their ids and map in excel with VLOOKUP to populate.  Hope this was helpful

Comment: Instead of adding a comment, make sure to edit your answer. This will ensure the full solution is read.